# Статистика stackoverflow на русском

Tags: обсуждение

Есть ли открытая статистика для пользователей с уровнем репутации ниже 25k?

Конкретно, интересует количество переходов из поисковиков и количество незарегистрированных пользователей, которые сюда попадают из этих самых поисковиков. Вообще, есть ли такая статистика?

Вот [эта страничка](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) не отражает то, что я ищу.

Comment: Для +25к есть статистика переходов из поисковиков, но нет статистики незарегистрированных пользователей.

Comment: @insolor значит половина из того что нужно есть. Может кто нибудь поделиться скриншотом? Или это не законно?

Comment: Без понятия, по идее нет, при переходе за 25к рейтинга никакого NDA не подписываешь)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wViJ.png

Comment: @insolor это великолепно, спасибо! Все таки google)